# Folder Permissions Issue

Tags: vb.net, security, io

I am trying to find out if a user has 'write' permission to a folder. From all the searching I've done, it seems way more complicated than it should be. I created a read-only folder on my C: drive called "NoWrite' and am trying to get the correct access info in VB (VS 2013). I have tried using 'Permission.Demand' on the folder and it doesn't error. I have tried 'DirectorySecurity' and it says I have access, but when I try and write a file, it errors out with an access error. I am so frustrated... Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

[EDIT] I am running 6 different folders through this code. The {folderName}\aTestFile.txt is being created in 5 of the folders that I do have 'write' access to, so I know that's working.

Here is my code:

```
Dim fldrInfo As New DirectoryInfo(FolderToCheck)
Dim ds As System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity = fldrInfo.GetAccessControl
    Dim fs As System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection = ds.GetAccessRules(True, True, Type.GetType("System.Security.Principal.NTAccount"))
    Dim wid As Principal.WindowsIdentity = Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent        
    For Each myAcc As System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule In fs
        Dim acc As System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule = DirectCast(myAcc, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule)
        If acc.IdentityReference.Value.ToUpper = wid.Name.ToUpper Then
            Debug.Print("Folder To Check = " & FolderToCheck)
            Debug.Print("Windows User ID = " & wid.Name)
            Debug.Print("Access Control Identity = " & acc.IdentityReference.ToString)
            Debug.Print("File System Rights = " & acc.FileSystemRights.ToString)
            Debug.Print("Access Control Type = " & acc.AccessControlType.ToString)
            Debug.Print("")
            If (acc.FileSystemRights And AccessControl.FileSystemRights.WriteData) = AccessControl.FileSystemRights.WriteData Then
                Try
                    Dim myDs As New FileStream(FolderToCheck & "\aTestFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Debug.Print(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

*And here is the output:

Folder To Check = C:\NoWrite

Windows User ID = KARL-HP\Karl

Access Control Identity = Karl-HP\Karl

File System Rights = FullControl

Access Control Type = Allow*

Access to the path 'C:\NoWrite\aTestFile.txt' is denied.

Comment: I tried to execute your code but `acc.IdentityReference.Value.ToUpper = wid.Name.ToUpper` was never true for me. Anyway I don´t get your concrete question: You created a folder with no write permission for user `Karl-HP\Karl` but try to write a file to it? Is it that you want `acc.FileSystemRights And AccessControl.FileSystemRights.WriteData) = AccessControl.FileSystemRights.WriteData` to be false so the exception won´t be thrown?

Comment: Exactly. This is just a test for a module I am writing just to see if I can get it working. I am working on a program where the user needs to set his preferences for several folders. A couple of the folders need to have write access. I have searched for hours looking for an elegant solution and thought I had it, but as you can see, the 'read only' test folder I created (C:\NoWrite) shows Allow/Full Control in my code, but the little test program blows up when I attempt to write a file to the folder.

Comment: I`m no windows expert but can it be that you as the owner of the folder always has write access to it? Can you change the owner to someone else and check again with your account?

Comment: Alex, thanks for your replies. I gave up and just added some sloppy code that attempts to create a file inside a Try-Catch block. I don't have any more time to screw around with this. I'll continue to look for a more elegant solution and will post here if I find it. I must be missing something... there has to be any easy way to see if the user has Write access to a folder. SMH